# Windows debugger closes source view, and I can't reopen it

Tags: debugging

This bug just started happening where I can't run the debugger without it closing every source tab. Not only that, but I can't view any of the tabs without reopening the entire solution.

If I <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f5</kbd> to run, it doesn't close the source-tabs however, which makes me think its about the debugger itself.

Anyone have a similar issue happen, that perhaps know how to remedy it?

Answer (score 1):

To get the immediate window back you can go to Debug --> Windows --> Immediate or you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> either will work to get it back.

Answer (score 1):

Only solution that works: Use ctrl-f5 to run without debugging, and f7 to build.

That way you can avoid the debugger breaking the source-view.